# Custom `ListView` or TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tablelayout

I need to create a `ListView` or `TableLayout` that each row consists of 3 columns and 3 buttons, something similar to that:

[image]

but the screen will not only contains this control will contains textfields and other layouts , I need a grid to take the shape like as the following (for example ).

Any idea on how to achieve that and how to handle `Button` clicks on it? 
As I am new to Android I don't know how to create that.

[image]

Comment: you have only these 3 rows or it will increase.. one more thing is when you create on expand button it will show some more views...

Comment: Edit and improve you question if you want users to help you. What is with those two images?(it is better if you provide a sketch of your **entire** layout like you would want it to be). Handle `Button` clicks? Where? What do you want to do on the click event? etc etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `ListView`is used mainly for mutable data. If you have some sort of data that can be displayed the same way everytime and it can grow/be deleted, then a ListView is a good option.

On the other way if you have static data, static Layouts (like TableLayout, LinearLayout, etc) are a good option. It all depends on what data you have and how you want to use it.

I hope you don't want to to do the same columns you have on that screenshot because you don't have that space on a smartphone.

Let's assume you want 3 columns, and that data is mutable.

You can use a [costum ListView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/) with a `LinearLayout` in the root with the `android:orientation="horizontal`. Then each element on you insert you need to use `layout_weight="1"` with the `android:layout_width="0dp"`. This combination guarantees that each element on your `ListView` row will have the same width, so it is kinda optional.

Your costum list row should seem something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    ...
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   ...
   android:layout_weight="1" />
...
```

To handle the button click you need to do a `setOnClickListener` in the Button when you get it in the `getView` method inside the adapter on your costum ListView.

Then you probly will have problems clicking the button and the ListView. A common way to solve that is to put the button as `android:focusable="false"` at the xml where you declare it. But one thing at a time ;)

EDIT (because of the comment: Adding a checkbox that disable/enables a button):

If you want a checkbox to disable/enable buttons you need to do some work on your `getView` in the adapter of your costum ListView.

You need to:

- Get your Checkbox using something like: `CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox) inflater.findViewById(R.id.checkboxid)` where the inflater is the one you defined in the getView and the checkboxid is the id you defined at your xml row.
- Save the button to be acessible in your checkbox listener: `myCheckBox.setTag(button)` where the button is the button you want to enable/disable and you can get him the same way you got the myCheckBox
- Set a `setOnCheckedChangeListener` on your checkbox where you change the visibility of your button depending on the state of the checkbox.

The last bullet should sound something like this:

```
myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Button myButton = (Button) buttonView.getTag();

        if ( isChecked ) 
            myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            // Use GONE if you want to get that space for other views
            myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

    }
});
```

Comment: what if I want to add checkbox such that when click on it the buttons on the row be activated and vise versa , best regards

Comment: If you are using the ListView then on your costum row you get the CheckBox with `findViewById`. You do `setOnCheckedChangeListener` and on that listener you can check when the checkbox changed to checked or unchecked. However, I belive you need to do a simple trick on this one. On your getView you need to do `view.setTag(button)`. The view on this case is the view that your are going to return and the button is the one you want to disable/enable. You need to do this so you can get the button on the listener you defined for checkbox. You can get the button doing `view.getTag()`

Comment: am totaly new to that, could u update the answer and give me example please

Comment: Updated the answer. Please try to do some things otherwise it becomes confusing. Start a by costum ListView then when you have all the looks you want go for your checkbox enabling/disabling buttons. This is actually 2 questions that are different. Don't try to do everything at once.

Comment: @AMH Just warning you that your bounty will be lost even if you don't give it to someone. Made the same mistake on user experience ;)

Answer (score 1):

i would advise you to see some application like this, as you new to android then have look at some applications,tutorials and controls too, No one can tell you how you would make this application, if it was a bug or something, then it would be answerable. But your question really vast. its not a problem of an application but how to develop whole application. I think better, you take a look at some applications or this [**link**](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) too. it would be helpful for u to have a start with android.

Answer (score 0):

I provide you the complete implementation of your problem. First create a list view in your xml

Name of file : Yourlist.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="@color/encode_view">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/info_list_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cancelinfobtn_id" >
    </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

After that create one more xml with one text box and one button like this

Filename=youCustomlayout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now create one custom list like this

```
    package com.menu.in;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.daffodilsw.client.android.R;



    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MyContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> userContact_List,userheading_list;
    private Context mcontext;   
    private View rowview;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public static ArrayList<Boolean > itemchecked=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    public MyContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList< String> usercontactheading_list,ArrayList<String> usercontactheading_list ) {
        super(context,R.layout.yourcustomlayout,usercontactheading_list);


        userheading_list=new ArrayList<String>();

        userheading_list=usercontactheading_list;
        mcontext=context;
         inflater = (LayoutInflater) mcontext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             rowview=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
            {
                rowview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_value_layout, parent, false);
            }

            TextView textView_heading = (TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            Button btn=(Button) rowview.findbyviewid(R.id.Button1);

            checkbox_detail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            textView_heading.setText(userheading_list.get(position));

          return rowview;
        }   


                }
```

Finally make an adapter in your main activity and then call constructor of adapter and set this adapter in your listview.